# Value [YoutubePlaylistID] at id of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: json, android-studio, android-volley, youtube-data-api

I am trying to create an application that will use the YoutTube Api to get all the videoIDs from a YouTube playlist. Then, the application will, hopefully, display all the videoIDs in a listView.

I am using Volley to handle all the HTTPs requests, I've added all the Google Api dependencies to my project, I've registered my app on the Google Developer Console and I've asked for Internet Permission in my Android Manifest file.

However, I run into this error (*"PLTpRNmzKHx18bIns2RMyw9czfPIn8SNpf"* is the ID of my playlist):

**Run Error**

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value PLTpRNmzKHx18bIns2RMyw9czfPIn8SNpf at id of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:101)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:616)
        at com.utilities.dog.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:102)
        at com.utilities.dog.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:93)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

I've seen people online getting the same problem. Apparently, defining a String variable before calling ".getJSONObject" can solve the problem. However, it did not worked for me so I reversed my code back to what it was.

Please take a look at my code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
ublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    [...]

    // Playlist URL I want to get data from.
    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=contentDetails%2C%20snippet%2C%20id&id=PLTpRNmzKHx18bIns2RMyw9czfPIn8SNpf&maxResults=25&key=[My API Key is here]";    

    private void getVideoIDs()
    {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                    for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject jsonVideoId =  jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                        String video_id = jsonVideoId.getString("videoID");
                        VideoDetails vd = new VideoDetails();
                        vd.setTitle(video_id);
                        videoDetailsArrayList.add(vd);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), video_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
                    myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

**VideoDetails.java** is a public class with getter and setter method for two string variables (title, videoId)

I am also wondering if I do need to call both 'ContentDetails' and 'Snippet' in order to get VideoIDs from a playlist or if I can just call one of the two.

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When needed to get *all video IDs* of a given playlist (in your case `PLTpRNmzKHx18bIns2RMyw9czfPIn8SNpf`), you should query the [PlaylistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint instead of [Playlists.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) endpoint.

This amounts to replacing `playlists` with `playlistItems` and `id` with `playlistId` in the invoking URL:

> `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2C%20snippet%2C%20id&playlistId=PLTpRNmzKHx18bIns2RMyw9czfPIn8SNpf&maxResults=25&key=[My API Key is here]`

If you only need *video IDs*, then suffices to have the [part](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#part) parameter be `part=ContentDetails`. Those video IDs are to be found at [`items[].contentDetails.videoId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#contentDetails.videoId).

Comment: Thank you! It works! May I ask another question ? Right now, I get an "Java.lang outOfBounds index:0, size:0" error from the ArrayList<VideoDetails> videoDetailsArrayList. It seems like despite the for loop where I call videoDetailsArrayList.add(vb) [in the onResponse void], nothing gets added to the ArrayList. This create an another error in the getCount() method in the listView adapter which I bypassed for now. Do you have any Idea on how to solve this?

Comment: But have you corrected the code of the `for` loop such that to access the video ID at `contentDetails.videoId`. Make sure (e.g. by logging it) that `jsonArray` in `onResponse` have a `length` of 3 (your playlist contains 3 items).

Comment: Also, note that your posted code references `videoID`, yet it should have been referencing `videoId`. See [JSONObject.getString](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getString-java.lang.String-): this method throws a `NullException` if the specified key doesn't exist.

Comment: I just checked the size of the jsonArray with `Log.i(TAG, "jsonArray Size : " + String.valueOf(jsonArray.length()));` and it returns zero. I also just changed `videoID` to `videoId`, thank you for pointing that. I am confused on how to correct the code for the loop... Do I need to access `contentDetails`instead of `id`before accessing videoId ? (I am sorry, i'm still a beginner.)

Comment: Yes, replace `id` with `contentDetails`. Also, post your URL once again (within a comment, editing out your app key, of course).

Comment: I just did and the length of the jsonArray still returns "0". Here's the URL : `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2C%20snippet%2C%20id&id=PLTpRNmzKHx18bIns2RMyw9czfPIn8SNpf&maxResults=25&key=[APIKEY]`

Comment: But you haven't replaced `id` with `playlistId` within that URL.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I though the URL you gave me in your response already had that changed so I didn't checked. It works perfectly now. Again, thank you a lot for your assistance.

Comment: No problem, but the URL posted in my response is valid: it has a `playlistId` parameter, not an `id` one.

Comment: Then, It's entirely my fault.

Comment: Indeed you maybe right on your own: for about 1 or 2 minutes the URL I posted had `id` in it; then I [corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61557861/revisions) that.